# Помогите спроектировать БД для регистрации сообщений

Tags: sql, sql-server, проектирование

Помогите спроектировать базу данных для регистрации сообщений.

Вот, что  у меня пока получилось:
[image: Схема]

- Должна быть предусмотрена возможность хранения сообщений в виде иерархии, т.е. пользователь может создавать папки и перемещать туда сообщения.
  Для хранения иерархических данных выбрал `Nested Set`.

**Вопрос:** Как связать сообщения с папками для их хранения. Сейчас я создал таблицу `MessageCatalogs`. Получится что-то вроде следующего:

```
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+----------------------+
| id          | name                 | lft | rgt |      messageId       |
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+----------------------+
|           1 | Входящие             |   1 |   10|         NULL         |
|           2 | NULL                 |   2 |   3 |           1          |
|           3 | NULL                 |   4 |   5 |           2          |
|           4 | Исходящие            |   10|   15|         NULL         |
|           5 | NULL                 |   11|   12|           5          |
|           6 | NULL                 |   13|   14|           8          |
|           4 | Тех(внутри Входящ.)  |   6 |   9 |         NULL         |
|           5 | NULL                 |   7 |   8 |           10         |
```

Может нужно объединить `MessageCatalogs` и `UserMessage` в 1 таблицу?

**UPD**

- 1 сообщение может быть отправлено сразу нескольким пользователям
- У каждого пользователя свой набор папок

Comment: Лишняя связь User-Message. *Для хранения иерархических данных выбрал Nested Set.* - почему? вернее - зачем... неужели сообщения и подпапки будут постоянно перетаскиваться туды-сюды?

Comment: Ну и вообще какая-то странная связь между UserMessage и MessageCatalog. Есть линк по id каталога, но неявно присутствует линк и по id сообщения - налицо потенциальное рассогласование.

Comment: Если сообщения лежат в папках, значит в папке может быть много сообщений. Если при этом одно сообщение не может быть более чем в одной папке то было бы логично хранить у сообщения id папки в которой оно лежит (а не наоборот).

Comment: @Akina, Nested Set - отличный механизм хранения данных, если будут часты операции чтения. Если бы они постоянно перетаскивались, выбрал бы AL или материализованные пути, или я не прав? Предлагаете объединить эти таблицы в 1?

Comment: `Nested Set` - это специализированная структура для хранения иерархических данных **и обработок, специфических для такого типа данных**. А у Вас таких обработок пока в упор не видать...

Comment: @Mike, Да, все верно => в папках может быть много сообщений. Я правильно понял, вы предлагает таблицу `Message` связать c `MessageCatalog`?

Comment: @romka.pm Объединение в одну таблицу имеет смысл только если сообщение может лежать не только в папке но и в другом сообщении. думаю это не требуется так что и объединять не стоит

Comment: У вас сейчас и так message и messagecatalog, только почему то связь не нарисована и почему то она идет в другую сторону (поле messageId в messagecatalog). хотя может и не нужна эта связь вообще. зависит от задачи. вы задачу очень слабо описали. такое ощущение что у вас одно сообщение может быть послано сразу нескольким пользователям, об этом в тексте нигде не сказано. И не понятно набор папок у каждого пользователя свой или один общий (сейчас по схеме кажется что общий)

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, дополнил вопрос.

Comment: но тогда у записей каталога должна быть ссылка на пользователя. И фактически мы получаем что у каждого пользователя свое дерево папок. Я слабо представляю как можно хранить множественные независимые деревья в nested sets. хотя конечно можно представить общий корень на котором расположены уже корневые папки пользователей

Comment: @Mike, C nested sets так и хотел сделать:) Может вы можете предложить другой вариант хранения такой иерархии. Спасибо.

Comment: Я считаю, что сейчас ок. Nested sets довольно "дорого" менять. Если на каждое сообщение будут обновляться границы NS, замедлится самое частое действие в вашей системе: отправка сообщения. Но да, почему вы выбрали NS вообще? Его мощь в том, чтобы легко (без рекурсии) было запрашивать элементы "из папки и её подпапок" и получать путь по иерархии (но его проще материализовывать каждый раз, я считаю), вам это правда нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько замечаний:

1. Сообщение всегда имеет получателя и отправителя - в вашей структуре этого не видно
2. Часто сообщения принято хранить/обрабатывать в виде *thread* - *нить беседы*, то есть сообщения с одной темой принято группировать вместе, хорошо бы как то поддержать это в вашей структуре.
3. Неясно как вы собираетесь хранить сообщение отправленное нескольким адресатам - или это как одно сообщение или как несколько сообщений разным адресатам? Из вашей структуры этого также не видно.
4. Иерархию видимо вы собираетесь сделать через каталоги. Если так, то достаточно следовать принципам построения файловых каталогов - то есть каталог всегда имеет 1-го родителя (ссылка на идентификатор каталога), если ссылка `null` - то это корневой каталог. Этого достаточно не нужно заморачиваться `left/right` ссылками как у вас - это лишние сущности.
5. И где же тело самого сообщения?

Comment: 1. прекрасно видно, отправитель в message, получатель в userMassage. 3. судя по приведенной структуре если несколько получателей - то несколько записей в userMessage. 5. тело сообщения видимо в поле text в message